# HighStock range selector drag event is not working on mobile device Ionic App

Tags: javascript, highcharts, ionic-framework

I want to display stock chart on my hybrid app, everything works fine except the drag event for the range selector at the bottom, I tested using the demo app, http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line. Using Chrome browser developer tool, turning on the mobile device mode and enable the touch screen event, the drag slider is not working.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's bug in Chrome dev tools? It's not really reliable testing device - on the native iPhone it works.

Comment: Forgot to mention it doesn't work on my Android 4.4.2 s4 Ionic App, I doubt if this is an Ionic issue or specific UIWebView?

Comment: Hard to say, maybe something overlaps the chart, so you can not click on it? Or maybe events are not passed on to the chart? Demo you posted works fine also on Android devices.

Comment: Generally ionic reset many events (like scroll divs etc), so probably this is a reason of skiping event support in chart.